# Find a list of words in an excel sheet

Tags: excel-2016

I am trying to find a list of words and if the word(s) exist then a count of each word) in an excel sheet which has multiple columns. For example:

1. Words to find

Apple 
Banana
Kale
Chard

2. Excel sheet columns

ID   Name  Feedback_1           Feedback_2
121  John  I don't like Bananas  Bananas
122  Adam  Kale is good          Apple
123  Rob   Chard sucks           Kale

3. Output

Apple 1
Banana 2
Kale 2
Chard 1

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to accomplish your goals? If so, post the code and you can get some better help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(FIND(G1,Rng_Feed),0)>0))}
```

where `Rng_Feed` is a continuous range of **Feedback_1** and **Feedback_2**. You can use `$C$2:$D$5` if you do not want to **name** this range nor use it in the formula.

[image: Solution]